# Where do I look in Drupal to see if magic quotes are turned on?

Tags: php, drupal

I'm having an issue that I suspect is being caused by the PHP feature Magic Quotes. Can I look somewhere in my Drupal 7 installation to see if they are enabled?

I'm using shared hosting (Bluehost), so I know I can contact them and check the status that way but I'm just wondering if Drupal allows me to see this and other PHP settings somehow.

Comment: I learned that this is an issue that needed to be solved in the PHP settings with my webhost. In my case, I needed to contact my host to get access to a file called php.ini, where I was able to fix the setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just upload a PHP file containing this:

```
<?php
echo "magic_quotes_gpc = ".ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')."\n";
echo "magic_quotes_runtime = ".ini_get('magic_quotes_runtime')."\n";
```

That will output the current settings.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. I made a slight change and these were the functions that returned the right values for me:  `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and
`get_magic_quotes_runtime()`

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 6 you can see in the settings.php file placed in sites/default/settings.php

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 6, sites/default/settings.php provides these two lines for magic quotes

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime',     0);
ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase',      0);
```

Comment: However, that wont tell you the setting of `magic_quotes_gpc` (since you can't set that once PHP has started)